# Ropsten Test Network

Tags: erc-20, wallets, ropsten

I have created a test token and deployed it on the ropsten test network. I have the full balance in my ether wallet. My question is how can I transfer this token to other wallets? How can I configure the token on other wallets using the rospsten test network?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use MetaMask, for example. Make sure you are on the Ropsten testnet and then educate the wallet about your token by giving the contract address. That's all there is to it because ERC20 (assuming that is applicable) standardizes the surface area.

Suppose you set up MetaMask in your browser. You'll get an account(s), and once the token contract is configured, you will see any tokens sent there.

It works the same on MyEtherWallet - also easy to experiment with, and most other wallets you might want to try.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Many thanks Rob. Actually that’s where I’m stuck. I created a new wallet on MyEtherWallet and transferred some tokens to it from the main wallet that holds all the tokens, the issue is that the new token is not appearing on the new wallet (the units get deducted from the main wallet but doesn’t appear on the new one). My question is what shall I do on the new wallet to make sure I receive the tokens?    I really appreciate your time :-)

Comment: I cant checking right at this moment. Look around for custom token. It just wants an address to know about the contract to inspect for you.